# What is the difference between the Package Language and the Site Language?

Tags: wp-cli, language

**What is the difference between the Package Language and the Site Language?**

If I run:

```
wp core language list
```

I get:

```
en_AU | English (Australia) | English (Australia) | active | available
```

If I run:

```
wp core version --extra
```

I get:

```
Package language:  en_US
```

Answer (score 1):

As you probably already know, WordPress supports language packs. Translation files that reside in `wp-content/languages`. Those are used to translate all the strings the user sees in WordPress.

WordPress also allows translation teams on WordPress.org to provide localized [release packages](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/translating/packaging-localized-wordpress/). These already come with the translation files included, plus a bit more. They can translate the readme file or bundle locale-specific functionality (e.g. custom plugins) to improve the UX for that locale.

For example, the [Japanese package](https://ja.wordpress.org/download/) contains the [WP Multibyte Batch](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multibyte-patch/) plugin and the readme is translated into Japanese as well. This is something the language packs cannot handle, as the readme is a simple HTML file. Similarly, the [German package](https://de.wordpress.org/download/) contains the original readme and a translated one.

Comment: I think the confusion here is about the values returned by wp-cli and not so much about what are the language packs themselves. Have to admit that I also find that output shown in the question inconsistent, or at least not clear.

Comment: To clarify, they downloaded the regular en_US package of WordPress (the one you got on wordpress.org/download) and then installed the en_AU language file. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Oh I get it now but it is truly confusing